# Gmail: Change forwarding address based on a received email

Tags: gmail

We have a web form that sends business enquiries to an automated inbox/tool. This tool then adds the details to our CRM system and sends a link to the newly-created record on to our fulfillment departments.

Often the automated inbox tool will error (for many reasons) meaning enquiries will not reach our broker/fulfillment departments.

When the tool errors, an email is sent with a specific subject to notify myself and others - so that we can edit the recipients on the web form to bypass our automated inbox.

Is it possible to put a Gmail account in between the web form and our automated inbox which automatically forwards emails to the automated inbox. Then, if the automated inbox sends the error email (to the gmail account) the Gmail account will then begin forwarding enquiries directly to our broker/fulfillment teams, until it's manually edited back?

Comment: Gmail filters by themselves won't allow you to do this. Are you using straight-up Gmail, or Google Apps email? If the latter, I'd expect you could make a mailing list. If the former, then perhaps sending the messages to a Google Group instead which the fulfillment teams could subscribe to. Honestly, though, you should be looking for a forms management solution.

Comment: I haven't created the Gmail account yet, I'm trying to work out the feasibility. A proper form management solution would be great, but that's not how my company works I'm afraid - I need to hack together a solution!